# I was solving my coding question for "number is a power of 2" and I have used the conditions but it didn't work?

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error, divide-by-zero

First,it is giving me syntax error on while loop condition. To get rid of zero division error here, I
have given the condition to while loop so that the number will not be equal to zero. Now, I don't know what to do?

```
def is_power_of_two(number):
  while (number!== 0 && number%2!=0):
    number = number / 2
   if number == 1:
     return True
   else
     return False
print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

I tried to solve it but it didn't worked.

Comment: (1) Your code's indentation is incorrect  (2) Python uses `and` to join conditions, not `&&`. Please fix them first.

Comment: could also use `is_power_of_two = lambda n: n>1 and bin(n)[3:].find('1') == -1`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there is one syntax error, you missed ":" after else.

Also, I changes conditions in while loop. Right now it gives answers that you mentioned

```
def is_power_of_two(number):
    while (number > 1) & (number % 2 == 0):
        number = number / 2
    if number == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(is_power_of_two(0)) # Should be False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # Should be False
```

False 
True 
True 
False